# sites running on nginx getting "too many redirects" message

Tags: nginx, wordpress

i have issue where sites are getting "too many redirects" error message when trying to browse to them. my static html sites are running fine, it is just the wordpress sites having the issue, anyone got idea why this is happening? i confirmed the htaccess file is in place.